# Sandstone getting soaked with water

Tags: gravity, forces, water, capillary-action

I have seen someone putting a sandstone in water. With only about 10% of the stone sitting in the water. One could see the stone getting soaked with water. So there must be a force, which lets the water climb up through the stone against gravity.

What is that force? Or is there some other effect present?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess will be that it's mainly the [effect of capillarity forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action) due to the porous quality of the stone surface. [This might also be a good read](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microfluidics/Capillary_effects).

Comment: Thanks, that must be it. There is a section called *Liquid transport in porous media* on your linked wiki article. That describes exactly what I have seen.